# create **one page** that can display different selected on the same page individually

Tags: jquery, sql

I would like to create **one page** that can display data from a specific company but not all companies together and each company selected displays/auto refreshes on that same page.

The idea is that even though companies are added to the table, the page can still display new companies and their related date individually.

e.g.

> Select company: 
>   Nestle
>   AMCO
>   ANSA Mcal
>   Minstry of Education

When an option is selected the page auto refreshes with the company's information from the company table and related tables of the selected company.

NB-- I'm a beginner in Oracle Apex so any help or advice on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Bind a change handler to the `select` and load the the required content in the handler to a content `div`, eg

HTML

```
<select id="company">
    <option value="o">Select a company?</option>
    <option value="1">Nestle</option>
    <option value="2">AMCO</option>
    <option value="3">ANSA Mcal</option>
    <option value="4">Minstry of Education</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#company').on('change', function(){
    var url;//url with company information to display
    switch ($(this).val()){
        case 1:
            url = '/nestle-info';
            break;
        case 2:
            url = '/amco-info';
            break;
        case 3:
            url = '/ansa-info';
            break;
        case 4:
            url = '/moe-info';
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    $('#content').load(url);
});
```